# How can the rendering of metadata be suppressed?

Tags: rendering

I have a problem with the rendering of animations: reviewing the saved file appears to inculde metadata (filename & framestart &frame end).
I would prefer not to include the metadata in each frame.

Comment: I edited you question if you don't like it you can rollback my edit.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the metadata stamp in the render settings. Probably you just checked it by accident.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To disable metadata overlayed over render-result uncheck the *Stamp Output* option under *Metadata* tab inside *Render* properties.

Blender also as of version 2.75 writes  **EXIF-type metadata** into images automatically (PNG, EXR, JPEG). To disable it uncheck all the check-boxes inside *Metadata* tab.

Comment: I had no answer to my problem but it was not enough. I had complained about an error in Blender: run a render motion, when you play the movie at the bottom center the text reads: namefile & 001.0256 (= start file and endfile). This is not professional: customers want a movie as clean in 3d Max example.Stamp output is another case not mine